# How can I reference a constant in a cs from an aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How can I reference a constant from constants.cs in page.aspx, I'm trying the following without any success

```
<%@ Import  Namespace="MyConstants" %>
<uc:MyControl ID="id1" runat="server" ConstantValue=" <%= Constants.TheValue %>" />
<uc:MyControl ID="id2" runat="server" ConstantValue=" <%# Constants.TheValue %>" />
<uc:MyControl ID="id3" runat="server" ConstantValue=" <%= MyConstants.Constants.TheValue %>" />
<uc:MyControl ID="id4" runat="server" ConstantValue=" <%# MyConstants.Constants.TheValue %>" />
```

And in `Constants.cs`

```
namespace MyConstants
public class Constants
public const string TheValue = "Hello, World";
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to import your namespace. You do this differently depending on your view engine.

If you're using WebForms:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Your.Namespace" %>
```

If you're using Razor with C#

```
@using Your.Namespace
```

If you're using Razor with VB.NET

```
@Imports Your.Namespace
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the fully qualified class-name?

```
<%= MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.Constants.TheValue %>
```

If that works, you can add this namespace to namespaces list in the web.config.

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="MyNamespace.MySubNamespace" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

And then you won't have to fully-qualify the class name in any page.

Answer (score 2):

You may specify the namespace for the class in the page as:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Your.Name.Space" %>
```

where `Your.Name.Space` contains the class `Constants`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `#` with server controls. So, you have to change your code like this one.

```
<!-- I have no references in page, is that missing? --> 
<uc:MyControl ID="id runat="server" ConstantValue=" <%# Constants.TheValue %>" />
```

Comment: When I try this the Constants.TheValue >> NULL

Answer (score 0):

why do not use the Property for your UserControl?:

UserControl Property :

```
public string ConstantValue { get; set; }
```

then you can use it :

```
<uc:MyControl ID="id" runat="server" ConstantValue="any string" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add static attribute to declaration, & you don't need to create instance of Constant class.

This way you can directly use Constant.TheValue

Happy Coding!!!